# Print class using format string

Tags: c++, oop

In my code, I just print the same object using format string. However, the result is not same. By my insight, I thought result should be `97 97 97`, but the outcome is `97 98 99`.

What happened with the output? I don't actually understand what's happening. Could you explain this?

```
class A {
public:
    int a, b, c;
    A() {
        this->a = 97;
        this->b = 98;
        this->c = 99;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A a;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, a, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C#, C++, and C are different languages. For C++, printing a class object with %d is undefined behavior. Vote to close for lack of minimal knowledge of the subject.

Comment: This poster is clearly a beginner, so instead of closing I suggest rather helping by pointing out the errors & wrongs and what should be done and where to get edifying info ... (PS: it reeks of arrogant elitism to want summary closing)

Comment: I think the OP *has* demonstrated at least minimal knowledge and made an effort to explain both expected and actual results along with a minimal compiling code sample. The only thing wrong with this question was the inappropriate tagging, which has been remedied.

Comment: You might consider picking a more reliable compiler. Clang by default refuses to compile this code. And if I disable the warnings manually, the resulting executable crashes with illegal hardware instruction error. So while the explanation about stack in the answer below is plausible, you can't count on this behavior to be consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is an object of type `A`, not an integer, which is what `%d` requires. This leads to undefined behaviour, which means anything goes. In this case, what appears to be happening is that one of the `a`s after the format string is occupying the same place on the stack that three `int` parameters would have occupied, and so its data members (`a`, `b` and `c`) are what the three `%d`s end up using.

To print the value 97 stored in `A::a` three times, you should do this:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", a.a, a.a, a.a);
```

Comment: Nice answer, they except you didn't(might cann't) explain the reason why that program print 97 98 99. that problem is not related with cpp. that's related with stack memory structure. and i solved this problem by my self. but this answer is very closed to solution. thank you.

Comment: @crazy_rudy: Thanks for the tick. But I don't understand your comment; I did explain, with reference to the stack, why you might be getting the output you are seeing.

Comment: yes you did. I mean every answerer except you could not explain the reason why.

Comment: @crazy_rudy: Ah. Sorry, I misunderstood the "they except you" bit. Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

A small rewrite of your code:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    A(){
        a = 97;
        b = 98;
        c = 99;
    }
void AFunction(int a, int b, int c){
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    A a;
    printf("(Expect: 97 97 97) %d %d %d\n", a.a, a.a, a.a);
    printf("(Expect: 97 98 99) %d %d %d\n", a.a, a.b, a.c);

    a.AFunction(1,2,3);
    printf("(Expect: 1 2 3) %d %d %d\n", a.a, a.b, a.c);

    return 0;
}
```

Using the `this->` syntax in the constructor is not wrong, just unnecessary. In the sample `AFunction()` it is necessary to use `this->` so that the compiler can figure out which `a, b` or `c` you are referring to.

See Marcelo's answer for why your code is wrong.

A good (and free! dowloadable) book is [Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've just cleaned up your code a bit to look more like C++:

```
class A {
public:
    // google for "constructor initialization list"
    A(): a_(97), b_(98), c_(99) 
    {}

    void print() const {
        // any member variable reference "a" implies "this->a"
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a_, b_, c_);
    }

// Having public member variables in a class is rarely a good idea
private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
    int c_;

    // In C++11 you can specify default values for the members like this:
    //
    // int a_ = 97;
    // int b_ = 98;
    // int c_ = 99;
    //
    // Then you can omit the constructor definition.
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    A a;
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```